# While installing Auto Cad application software facing Error 1606

Tags: autocad

i am using windows 8 64 bit, while installation autocad software, in the begin of installation
the error 1606 occured , what to do to install the autocad in windows 8 64 bit, why this problem is taking place
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoCAD versions prior than 2014 are not compatible with Win8, see [here for autodesk products compatibility list](https://www.google.fr/search?aq=f&oq=autocad+windows+8+compatibility&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=autocad+windows+8+compatibility)

Since you're aware of that, I've installed acad 2012 on win 8 and I haven't got any issue once installed.

Your issue strongly looks like the one described here: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?siteID=123112&id=8164400&linkID=9240617

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Acad 2010 on a Win8.1 x64. What i did is i turned off windows defender then i used a 32 bit setup file using 64bit files...i took the 32bit setup file pasted it in the 64bit files after removing the Acad 64bit setup. Worked for me.